# How to automatically certain emails in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, forwarding

I have two email accounts (let's call them `account 1` and `account 2`).

When I receive an email on `account 1` and `account 2` is not in the `to` or `CC` fields, I want it to be forwarded automatically to `account 2`.

What kind of rules are required to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information. You can setup a 'Forwarder' depending on your host. Google's Gmail has an option to forward mail to another host/address, and I am sure there are many different ways to accomplish this depending on the email client/host/provider.